# Возможно ли убрать поля "Content-Type" и "Content-Length" из заголовка http-ответа, используя библиотеку libevent?

Tags: http, веб-сервер, libevent

Для запросов, предполагающих ответ без контента, хотелось бы убрать поля Content-Length и Content-Type.

Вызовы функций

```
    evhttp_remove_header(req->output_headers, "Content-Length");
    evhttp_remove_header(req->output_headers, "Content-Type");
```

результата не дают, т.к. до этих вызовов поля не содержатся в заголовке ответа, а сразу после отправки

```
evhttp_send_reply(req, 200, "OK", nullptr);
```

появляются. Следовательно, библиотека добавляет их во время отправки. Возможно ли, как-то убрать эти поля?

Comment: Да, это сработало! Благодарю!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно, к примеру, использовать код **204 No Content**, который относится к успешным ответам, однако не должен содержать тела ответа и, как следствие, описывающих его заголовков.

В libevent [тело ответа должно отсутствовать в любом из следующих случаев](https://github.com/libevent/libevent/blob/306747e51c1f0de679a3b165b9429418c89f8d6a/http.c#L341-L354):

- Статус ответа:

  - 204 No Content
  - 304 Not Modified
  - любой 1хх (информирующий)
- Метод запроса — `HEAD`.

Логика ссылается на [RFC 2616, раздел 4.3](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.3):

> Все ответы на запросы методом `HEAD` ОБЯЗАНЫ НЕ включать в себя тело сообщения, даже если так может показаться из заголовков о сущности. Ответы со статусами 1хх (информирующие), 204 (no content, нет содержимого) и 304 (not modified, не изменилось) ОБЯЗАНЫ НЕ включать в себя тело ответа. Все прочие ответы включают в себя тело ответа, хотя оно МОЖЕТ быть нулевой длины.

Впрочем, я не вижу тут однозначного категоричного утверждения о том, что "все прочие ответы" *обязаны* иметь тело ответа, как это предполагает код libevent.